# Is it ok to lower grade around a well head instead of raising it?

Tags: well, well-pump

I recently learned that well heads should be about a foot or more about ground; ours is only about 3-4" above ground. The well drillers said we really should have it raised and have a better cap put on. This all makes sense but raising it is apparently quite costly. Would it be just as well to dig around the well head to increase the distance from the top of the well head to the ground? We already have a cover that goes all around it to prevent larger animals getting into the well head.

Comment: If you dig out around the head, won't you create a pit which will fill with rain water?

Comment: Shop around. Assuming a typical steel well casing it's a straightforward job that should not cost "thousands" - thread on or weld on a short section of wall casing, depending how the top of the current casing is finished.

Comment: Is the top threaded?  You can't buy a short extension and screw it on?

Comment: A foot of 4 or 6” steel pipe, new cap watertight/ underground electrical splice couple of feet of water pipe and couplings.  Not that much in materials, this could be welded with a home quality 110v  wire welder $300+ , well cap 25$, splice kit & wire 50$, pipe and couplings 10-50$ depending on type of pipe. So you can see even a thousand sounds crazy high even purchasing a small welder.

Comment: If it is cast iron, thread it . If it is steel ,weld it.

Comment: @bla good point, cast iron is not for welding (unless you’re really, really, really into control cooling,,,)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the well casing should be above ground. As long as the ground water doesn’t get within 1” of the top I would not mess with it. For example my last house the casing was at ground level. I was on the side of a mountain I dug the high side down a few inches then graded the low side away even with the heaviest rains the water flowing down the hill never got close so it was fine. It may have been ok but I would rather a little safety margin.

If you don’t have high water issues I would say it is ok. I would protect it so it is not a spot that a dog can pee on it. We always put wishing well structures there if not in a well house. One really neat one I saw had a artificial bolder over it it looked really neat for that area.

So if you don’t have high water issues I would not worry. If you do have water over the cap I would probably find someone else a bit more reasonable To extend the casing.

Comment: In my area you would be breaking the law if you welded your own extension on unless you happened to be a licensed well driller. But licensed well drillers can be had at fairly reasonable rates when it's not a "right now emergency" call.

Comment: People drill there own wells here in some areas the biggest issue I know of is capping the top 20’ to code so no ground water can enter along the casing.

Answer (score 1):

There are extensions available in kit form. You could also get a 2' piece of casing and add a coupler such as this well casing coupler. https://www.aquascience.net/skinner-6-well-casing-coupler. No welding etc. You can google "well casing extension kit" for lots of variations and instructions on how to install them.